# how to remove a field from document after 30 min in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have schema like below, i want to remove only the token after 4 hours of its creationDate i tried the expire:"4 hour" but this deletes all the document  :

```
const driverSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> npm install jsonwebtoken

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
jwt.sign({
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: '0.5h' });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i need to remove the token from mongo db document , this token is not a jwt token